# How do I match the string?

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I've written a method for matching string input to a certain pattern before the program moves forward but Netbeans IDE is telling me that the escape characters are illegal. I'm not sure how to fix it.

The method is as follows:

```
public static boolean patternMatch(String ct){
    if(ct.equals("\d\d:\d\dam")){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        if(ct.equals("\d\d:\d\dpm"))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The pattern is a time pattern that needs to match `##:##am` or `##:##pm` based on the input from the user. Is this one going to work? Is there a way I can get it to match the input with the pattern this way?

Comment: hmm. You need to use `matches()` and two slashes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First .. **don't** forget to double escaping because of Java (`\\d`)!!

Use regex function `match()` that returns `boolean` as well. You can use classes `Matcher` and `Pattern` from the default library `java.util.regex.`.

```
public static boolean patternMatch(String ct) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d\\d:\\d\\d[ap]m");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(ct);
    return m.matches();
}
```

Note that you can easily avoid `if-else` statement using `[ap]m` that mathes one of `a` or `p` giving success on both `am` and `pm`.

However the easiest and direct way is:

```
return ct.matches("\\d\\d:\\d\\d[ap]m");
```

Comment: Wonderful, this is precisely what I needed. Thank you! Now to fix up the leading zero issue and this assignment is finally done aside from documentation >.<

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean patternMatch(String ct){
    return ct.matches("\\d\\d:\\d\\d[ap]m");
}
```

This will check if the string matches either am or pm in one test, so your method is greatly simplified.